# Discretization of a continuous distribution

Tags: sampling, continuous-data

I have two variation of the same problem.

A) Assume you sample $m$ points, $x_1,x_2,...x_m$, drawn i.i.d from a continuous distribution  of a random variable $X$. We reorder the points so $x_1<x_2<...<x_m$. You may assume there exists a density $f(x)$. To each point you assign the weight (or probability) of the interval $[(x_{i-1}+x_i)/2,(x_{i}+x_{i+1})/2]$ (we set $x_0=-\infty$, $x_{m+1}=\infty$). Namely:
$$P(X'=x_i)=\int_{(x_{i-1}+x_{i})/2}^{(x_{i+1}+x_{i})/2} f(x)dx $$

This provides a granularization of the continuous random variable $X$ to a discrete RV $X'$.
I'm interested in obtaining bounds on the expected value of $$|E(X)-E(X')|$$ as a function of the number of points $m$. If it is possible to obtain bounds on 
$$\Pr\left(|E(X)-E(X')|>\delta \right)$$ this would be great.
 Any tip would be helpful!

B) A similar version of the problem is when there are $n$ i.i.d samples drawn from a distribution of a random variable $X$. We denote the empirical average as $<x^{(n)}>$.  A subset of $m$ points are selected from the set of $n$ samples. We have $n\gg m\gg 1$. The weights of each point $x_i$, $i=1..n$ is the number of points (from the set of $n$ initial points) in the interval $[(x_{i-1}+x_i)/2,(x_{i}+x_{i+1})/2]$. As before, I'm interested in $$|<x^{(n)}>-<x^{(m)}>|$$ as a function of $m$ and $n$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!